# Float messes child width

Tags: html, css

I remember I have ran into this before but I cannot stress it enough to remember the workaround.. I have this drop down menu that I fiddled for ease. The problem is when you hover over the dot see how the children elements are wrapped and not displayed on a single line. How can I have them looking normally?

http://jsfiddle.net/N45P7/

**HTML**

```
<div class='addedForDisplayPurposes'>
    <div class="optionsList"> <span>•</span>

        <div class="optionsHolder">
            <div data-id="asdasd" class="socInt">Add Friend</div> <a href="#">Send Message</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.addedForDisplayPurposes {
    width:300px;
}
.optionsList {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:right;
}
.optionsList > span {
    font-size:20px;
    color:black;
}
.optionsList:hover > span {
    color:white;
}
.optionsList:hover .optionsHolder {
    display:inline-block;
}
.optionsHolder {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    background:white;
    border:solid black 1px;
    padding:5px 0 5px 0;
    z-index:3;
}
.optionsHolder > * {
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.optionsHolder > *:hover {
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `.addedForDisplayPurposes` wrapper element? Is this part of the actual layout?

Comment: Will you ever have more than one option in the `.optionsList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes and your problem will be solved.

```
.optionsHolder {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 15px;
    right: 0;
    background: white;
    border: solid black 1px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 140px;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you cannot make any changes to the `width`,  add a `white-space:nowrap;` for the text to wrap in one line.

**For Instance,**

```
.optionsHolder {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 15px;
    right: 0;
    background: white;
    border: solid black 1px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    z-index: 3;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Hope this helps now.

Comment: Then add a `white-space:nowrap;` instead of width. - @php_nub_qq

Comment: This looks more of a hack rather than what would be the actual solution, although I'm sticking with this until, if, the solution is given. Will accept in case of no other answers. Thanks!

Comment: `white-space:nowrap;` is not a hack. It is a proper CSS property to wrap the text in one line. - @php_nub_qq

Comment: I thought it was because the padding below the anchor wasn't displaying properly but I added block display to all option elements and that seemed to do the trick

Comment: `Block` is converting any element into a block or giving them the default characteristics like the `Div` to make it display on the page as one full block. Where as `whitespace:nowrap;` is used specifically for textual elements. Where as HACK is a mixture of things tried to set with not necessarily logical permutations to achive the output. Like what you have the most in your fiddle. :) I hope you are now clear between both. - @php_nub_qq

Comment: `Like what you have the most in your fiddle` Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36263/discussion-between-nathan-lee-and-php-nub-qq)

Answer (score 0):

### Use CSS table display types

An alternative is to use the display property:

```css
.optionsList:hover .optionsHolder {
    display: table;
}
.optionsHolder {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    background:white;
    border:solid black 1px;
    padding:5px 0 5px 0;
    z-index:3;
}
.optionsHolder > * {
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

For `.optionsHolder`, set `display: table` and for the child elements, set `display: table-cell`.

This will allow the child elements to display on a single line in a parent with a shrink-to-fit width.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/DmbMV/